# Casting scrolls while hiding?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, stealth

How do you rule on a rogue that is invisible (superior invisibility), incorporeal, hiding in plain sight (sop) casting from scrolls?

Does he get penalties to hide?

Does the scroll emit lights which would affect the hiding?

If the rogue casts a spell from the scroll that needs verbal components, does this mean that the rogue can be heard by other creatures?

Do targets of spells get a spot check to possibly spot the rogue/caster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Casting a spell from a scroll is *casting the spell*. With the exception of the training and spell slot required to do it, and the need for the piece of paper, it’s all exactly the same.

One of those differences does matter here, though: the rogue has to be able to **see** the scroll to read it. So they need *see invisibility* or similar. Probably not a deal-breaker, but a thing to be aware of.

> Does he get penalities to hide?

If the spell involves an attack, “It’s practically impossible (−20 penalty) to hide,” and at least personally I’d extend that to include any spell that clearly has something projected from the caster’s space, e.g. *fireball*, even if there’s no attack roll involved. (Besides, in context, the word “attack” is probably meant in its broad sense of “any offensive action that directly targets a creature,” as opposed to the narrow sense of “involving an attack roll,” though 3.5e is ***notoriously*** unspecific about these two most of the time.)

On the other hand, if it’s like *summon monster* or something, then no, there isn’t any visual indication of the caster’s presence, the monster just appears suddenly.

> Does the scroll emits lights which would affect the hiding?

Nothing says the scroll itself does. The spell being cast very well might, though for a lot of spells that’s going to be a judgment call for the DM because the descriptions aren’t detailed enough. So like, *light* or probably any fire spell, sure, there’s light emitted. For *summon monster*, probably not, or at least nothing particularly suggests there is. But magic is often flashy and the rules just aren’t clear about it.

> If the rogue casts a spell from the scroll that needs verbal components, does this mean that the rogue can be heard by other creatures?

Yes, the rogue needs to “complete” the spell, i.e. perform “the final gestures, words, and so on.” If the spell has a verbal component, completing it will involve speaking. Less or less-complicated speaking, but it will still be audible. Note that the rules specify that “you must […] speak in a strong voice” for verbal components, so no whispering is allowed.

This also means that *silence* or *superior invisibility* prevents verbal components (a fact both spells mention explicitly). On the other hand, being incorporeal, to my mind, shouldn’t block speaking—incorporeal creatures are described speaking, or wailing or shrieking or what have you, all the time. But there is no way to perform a verbal components silently—either you can speak and thus be heard, or you cannot and can’t use verbal spells.

> Do targets of spells get a spot check to possibly spot the rogue/caster?

Yes—again, “It’s practically impossible (−20 penalty) to hide,” which means a new round of Spot vs. Hide, Listen vs. Move Silently is appropriate.

Comment: Problem is: the caster must be able to read the scroll in order to activate it. But if the rogue is invisible, the scroll and the writing on it are invisible too...

Comment: @PeregrinTook I’ve always assumed invisible creatures are able to see themselves (and their equipment made invisible by the same spell). No idea if that’s backed up or not by the rules though.

Comment: @KRyan when you say about casting a scroll you said that the rogue needs to "speak in a strong voice”, so when incorporeal the rogue emits no sounds and cannot cast a spell. On the same line casters with superior invisibility emits no sound. Does this mean that those casters cannot cast spells because they make no sound?

Comment: @Digius Magical silence blocks verbal components. [*Silence* is explicit about it](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/silence.htm), but the same principle applies generally. The issue for me is that my read of incorporeality (I need to double-check *superior invisibility*) blocks the sound of movement, like breathing, heartbeat, footsteps, mini-collisions with environment that one could Listen for or try Move Silently to minimize. I’m not sure they block intentional speech, as *silence* does. Anyway, either they allow speech and you can be heard, or they don’t and verbal components are out.

Comment: @Digius Checked *superior invisibility*, and it explicitly says “radiates a silence […] preventing speech and the casting of spells with somatic [sic] components,” so that answers that, as long as you ignore the typo.

Comment: @Digius Just noticed that only the _Complete Arcane_ version notes preventing “somatic” (in context: verbal) components—the _Spell Compendium_ version doesn’t mention it. As the later printing, _Spell Compendium_ takes precedence, but... it just doesn’t give us anything to go on. Anyway, it still definitely doesn’t let you perform verbal components silently—either you can perform them, and can be heard doing so, or the spell makes you utterly and cannot perform verbal components. There is no version of this where you can be silent **and** complete verbal components.

Comment: There are several ways to be silent with spells that have a verbal component.  The metamagic feat Silent Spell (PHB p.100), as well as the Ring of Silent Spells (MIC p.127) jump immediately to mind but there's likely others.

Comment: @Kuro_Neko Both of those _remove the verbal component_, they don’t make you capable of completing verbal components silently.

Comment: @KRyan That's a good point, and regarding scrolls the feat would be a non-starter unless the scroll was intentionally created at a higher level than necessary.  But my reading of the ring's ability seems like it should still work with default scrolls.

Comment: @Kuro_Neko Yes, the *ring* would work, it just doesn’t precisely do the thing I said couldn’t be done. As for Silent Spell, it could be applied to a scroll via metamagic spell-completion, which is a class feature of 11th-level artificers, and maybe, arguably, a *metamagic rod of silent spell*. Plus there’s the Sudden Silent feat in _Complete Arcane_.